# Check if a variable string exist in a text file

Tags: python, text, replace, txtextcontrol

So guys, i'm tryng to make a password generator but i'm having this trouble:

First, the code i use for tests:

```
idTest= "TEST"
passwrd= str(random.randint(11, 99))


if not os.path.exists('Senhas.txt'):
    txtFileW = open('Senhas.txt', 'w')
    txtFileW.writelines(f'{idTest}: {passwrd}\n')
    txtFileW.close()
else:
    txtFileA = open('Senhas.txt', 'a')
    txtFileA.write(f'{idTest}: {passwrd}\n')
    txtFileA.close()

print(f'{idTest}: {passwrd}')
```

Well, what i'm expecting is something like this:

```
else:
    with open('Senhas.txt', 'r+') as opened:
        opened.read()
        for lines in opened:
            if something == idTest:
                lines.replace(f'{something}', f'{idTest}')
            else:
                break
txtFileA = open('Senhas.txt', 'a')
txtFileA.write(f'{idTest}: {passwrd}\n')
txtFileA.close()

print(f'{idTest}: {passwrd}')
```

I've searched for it but all i've found are ways to separate it in 2 files (for my project it doesn't match) or with "static" strings, that doesn't match for me as well.

Comment: Where is the ```something``` variable coming from?

Comment: @EdwinCruz "something" is actually _something_ in the text file

Comment: Why doesn't the loop use `lines`?

Comment: `opened.replace()` makes no sense. `opened` is a file, it doesn't have a `replace()` method. Did you mean `lines.replace()`?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're tryhing to do with that loop. Are you trying to replace a user's password with a new password?

Comment: @Barmar yup, thx for the tip; i'll fix it in the post

Comment: @Barmar I want that if the "id" alread is in the file; it changes the password

Comment: I suspect what you want is something like `if lines.startswith(idTest + ':')`

Comment: Why are you using a text file instead of a database or JSON?

Comment: @Barmar i'm a very beginner, that's just for study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module to update the file in place.

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input(files=('Senhas.txt'), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if (line.startswith(idTest+':'):
            print(f'{idTest}: {passwrd}')
        else:
            print(line)
```